region above the cone and inside the sphere
I've come across a problem where
\begin{array}{c}
\mbox{I have to compute the volume of the region}
\\ \mbox{above the cone}\
z^2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\ \mbox{and inside the sphere}\ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1
\end{array}

I can't understand one thing, since this equation of the cone depicts an open $\mbox{cone ?}$, what would be the region above the cone and inside the sphere I can include the image of what I sketched for a better view on how I tried to do the problem I just can't seem to pinpoint what would be the region above the cone and inside the sphere as stated in my problem requirements.



"Above the cone" means anything with a $z$ coordinate above the cone. If you prefer to think about it this way, you're going to be integrating over the intersection of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1$ (the sphere) and $z \ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (the cone).

Note: I write $z$ and not $z^2$ here since your problem text and your picture depict an actual cone, but with $z^2$ you get something quite different.

The end result looks like this ice cream cone sort of shape. (Desmos demo here.)


Thanks so much, sorry I missed the z^2 in my explanation, I just have one small question so in this case with the equation of the cone is it always going to be one that extends upwards across the z-axis and has its apex on the origin in This case?

In this case, if the equation you're dealing with is $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then yes. If you're dealing with the equation $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$, then you have a double-tipped cone (like you posted originally). In that case ... I would say the problem is ambiguously worded at best, but gun to my head I would interpret it the same as I would the $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (volume above the upper of the two cones, below the sphere, like depicted in my post).
